# MoveToElement doesn't work anymore since Firefox 48

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox-marionette, geckodriver

I've seen people had this problem since the introduction of the Marionette webdriver but still couldn't find a solution for my thingy.
Basically i need to hover an element and after that click on another element contained by the first one.
But ever since the new Marionette webdriver this line didn't worked anymore in Firefox

```
action.MoveToElement(element);
action.Build().Perform();
```

With the ChromeDriver the lines are executed without any issues but with firefox i always get an error at the second line:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotImplementedException'
>   occurred in WebDriver.dll
>
> Additional information: POST
>   /session/105178c5-3084-4b67-96a6-24045a61628d/moveto did not match a
>   known command

I use Selenium Webdriver with C#, has anyone figured out a way to solve the hovering?

Comment: Not yet that I know of.  Browser stack adding version 48 made things even worse.  I'm specifying version 46 in my tests until(/if) this improves.  Rolled back firefox on my machine to 46.  Will increasingly be a problem, because I'd rather be testing against the latest version of course.